# Flux and server record validation and id creation

Tags: flux

I am trying to understand Flux and implement it for Angular app 
I have problem with record creation form flow (it does not matter that it's Angular - the question is about pattern and problem is the same with React) .

Let's consider this simple and common scenario:

1. modal form dialog with 'save' button for item creation.
2. when user clicks 'save' form submits data to server.
3. if there is an error it's displayed in the form
4. if 'save' succeeded, ID generated by server is in response, form is closed, record is refreshed using ID

Normally I would call service's method which returns promise with ID or ERRORS

How can I implement this with Flux's 'fire and forget' actions?

How can I retrieve server status so I could close dialog or leave it opened with errors displayed?

How can I retrieve ID from server so I could refresh my data from Store using it's ID?

And How can I retrieve validation errors from server?

Comment: Are you attempting to use the flux pattern that's usually used with ReactJS in your Angular application?

Comment: "trying to understand Flux and implement it for Angular app"

Comment: I'm just clarifying that you're talking about the flux pattern used with React and not another technology.  If this is the case, then have you set up your Actions and Store?

Comment: Yep. Flux is already used w. other frameworks inc. Angular but I couldn't find pattern/sample for server interaction when view needs to update itself with status of server api call.

I found 2 solutions:
1. view calls server using promise to retrieve status, then server creates action to update data in store. i don't like idea of view communicating with server - i think it should belong to Store
2. view calls store that calls server api to update itself. no way to retrieve server status

Answer (score 0):

With flux you don't utilise promises like you normally would.  Your view should call a method in your Actions, which performs an ajax request.  This ajax request should have a success/error callback, which in turn would dispatch an event along with the data that has been returned from the server.

Your store will then pick up this dispatch action and store it.  The store will emit an event, which should cause your view to request the updated data from the store.

This still applies even for validation errors that your server returns.  The server will return your validation errors, which in turn will get dispatched to the store, in which your view will pick up the validation status/messages.

e.g.

**Actions.js**

```
function postData(data, dialogId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/api/endpoint",
      data: data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(response) {
          AppDispatcher.dispatch({
             actionType: "success",
             data: response,
             dialogId: dialogId
          });
      },
      error: function(error) {
          AppDispatcher.dispatch({
             actionType: "error",
             error: error,
             dialogId: dialogId
          });
      })
    });
}
```

Comment: closer (it's p.2 from my comment above and i like it) but there is a problem. let's say that dialog subscribes to this action and after it receives 'success' it closes the dialog. But how can i be sure that this 'success' action is in response to THIS dialog's 'save' action? I mean -  it is async so It could be some other 'create' action from other parts of application (if it's modal it should not be a problem but I was thinking about more general pattern). I need to be 100% sure that MY post data was persisted (check field by field or use update token or  check timestamp... still don't know)

Comment: Could you have an ID for the dialog, which you pass to your action?  The action doesn't need to pass the dialog ID to the server, but simply dispatch it to the store.  When your Angular controller then receives the data from the store, it can check the ID in the data to determine if the action is for that dialog.

Comment: Exactly what i was thinking (i called it 'update token'). I need to POC it to wrap my head around it